# What causes "Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTargetDatastore' parameter 0"?

Tags: spring, gradle, groovy, kotlin, grails-orm

I'm a complete novice regarding Spring applications, and I'm trying to integrate a project using Kotlin + Spring + GORM (Which requires usage of Groovy). When I try to run it I get:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTargetDatastore' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

I have just 5 files in the project, including the build.gradle.

**Message.groovy**

```
import grails.gorm.annotation.Entity
import groovy.transform.ToString
import org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity

@ToString
@Entity
class Message implements GormEntity<Message> {
    String user;
    String date;
    String message;
}
```

**Message.service**

```
import domain.Message
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@CompileStatic
@grails.gorm.services.Service(Message)
@Service
interface MessageService {
    List<Message> findAll()
}
```

**MessageController.groovy**

```
@RestController
@Transactional
class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    MessageService messageService

    @RequestMapping("/")
    List<String> index() {
        return messageService.findAll().collect { "[" + it.user + "@" + it.date + ": " + it.message + "]" }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String save(@RequestBody Message message) {
        message.save()
        return "Saved"
    }
}
```

**App.kt**

```
@SpringBootApplication
class SimManagerApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    SpringApplication.run(SimManagerApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

**build.gradle dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin')
    compile('com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.flywaydb:flyway-core')
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")

    compile("com.h2database:h2")

    compile("eu.vaadinonkotlin:vok-rest:0.6.2")
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.4')
    compile("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.2.0")

    compile "org.grails:gorm-hibernate5-spring-boot:6.1.6.RELEASE"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.0.Final"

    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.5.0"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:8.5.0"
    runtime "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10"

}
```

and as simple as that, the project fails to start. What, exactly, causes the UnsatisfiedDependencyException? Is there a simple straightforward way to solve it?.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please provide the full error. usually it contains the problem description.

Comment: Slightly related, but do you really need GORM? I find that Spring Data JPA often provides the same ease of use, plus it might be a little bit better aligned with the rest of Spring. Also, why are you using Groovy and Kotlin in the same project? That's asking for problems.